# Checkbox Created with CreateWindow Disappears on Resize

Tags: checkbox, delphi-6, createwindow

I'm adding a checkbox to the BrowseForFolder dialog using the following calls...

```
ControlCreateStyles := WS_CHILD or {WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or} WS_VISIBLE or WS_TABSTOP or BS_CHECKBOX;
ChkBoxHdl := CreateWindow('BUTTON', PChar(ChkBoxCap), ControlCreateStyles,
   Left, Top, Width, Height, Wnd, FB_CHECKBOX_ID, HInstance, nil);
```

The checkbox displays and operates correctly. However, when I resize the dialog down to its smallest size, the checkbox and caption disappear. Resizing the dialog causes the checkbox to reappear but not consistently. I tried enabling WS_CLIPSIBLINGS but doing so causes the component to not display at all.

Here is my test unit...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function BrowseForFolder(Title, Caption: string; const InitFolder: string = ''; DoNewBtn: Boolean = True; DoCheckBox: Boolean = False): string;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ShowCheckBox: Boolean = False;
  DialogCaption: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  ShlObj, FileCtrl;

const
  BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE = $40;
  BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON = $200;
  FB_CHECKBOX_ID = 4005;

var
  lg_StartFolder: String;
  OldWndProc: Pointer;

function WndProcLocal(HWindow: HWND; MsgId: UINT; wP: WPARAM; lP: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  NewFolder: string;
  Cnt: Integer;
  maxwidth: Integer;
  MyFB: HWND;

begin
  if (MsgId = WM_COMMAND) and (wP = FB_CHECKBOX_ID) then begin
    Result := 0;
    NewFolder := '';
    Cnt := 0;

    if (IsDlgButtonChecked(HWindow, FB_CHECKBOX_ID) = 0) then begin
      CheckDlgButton(HWindow, FB_CHECKBOX_ID, BST_CHECKED);
      // Do Something
    end
    else begin
      CheckDlgButton(HWindow, FB_CHECKBOX_ID, BST_UNCHECKED);
      // Do Something
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if (MsgId = WM_SHOWWINDOW) then begin
      // Do Something
    end
    else if (MsgId = WM_SIZE) then begin
      // Do Something
    end
    else if (MsgId = WM_MOVE) then begin
      // Do Something
    end;
    Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, HWindow, MsgId, wP, lP);
  end;
end;

function BrowseForFolderCallBack(Wnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; lParam, lpData: LPARAM): Integer stdcall;
var
  ControlCreateStyles: Integer;
  ChkBoxCap: String;
  ChkBoxHdl: HWND;
  Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer;
  PPI: Integer;
  Cnv: TCanvas;
  TempFont: TFont;

begin
  Result := 0;
  if uMsg = BFFM_INITIALIZED then begin
    if ShowCheckBox then begin
      Left := 16;
      Top := 32;
      //Width := ?; { Calculated next based on caption }
      Height := 16;

      ChkBoxCap := 'Checkbox Caption';

      Cnv := TCanvas.Create;
      try
        Cnv.Handle := GetDC(Wnd);
        Width := Height * 2 + Cnv.TextWidth(ChkBoxCap);
      finally
        Cnv.Free;
      end;

      ControlCreateStyles := WS_CHILD or {WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or} WS_VISIBLE or WS_TABSTOP or BS_CHECKBOX;
      ChkBoxHdl := CreateWindow('BUTTON', PChar(ChkBoxCap), ControlCreateStyles,
         Left, Top, Width, Height, Wnd, FB_CHECKBOX_ID, HInstance, nil);

      TempFont := nil;
      TempFont := TFont.Create;
      TempFont.Assign(Screen.IconFont);
      try
        PostMessage(ChkBoxHdl, WM_SETFONT, Longint(TempFont.Handle), MAKELPARAM(1, 0));
      finally
        TempFont.Free;
      end;

      CheckDlgButton(Wnd, FB_CHECKBOX_ID, BST_UNCHECKED); { Should always default to False }

      //EnableWindow(ChkBoxHdl, True); { Necessary? }
    end; { ShowCheckBox }

    SetWindowText(Wnd, PChar(DialogCaption));

    SendMessage(Wnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, 1, Integer(@lg_StartFolder[1]));
    OldWndProc := Pointer(GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_WNDPROC));
    SetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_WNDPROC, Longint(@WndProcLocal));
  end;
end;

function BrowseForFolder(Title, Caption: string; const InitFolder: string = ''; DoNewBtn: Boolean = True; DoCheckBox: Boolean = False): string;
var
  lpItemID: PItemIDList;
  BrowseInfo: TBrowseInfo;
  DisplayName: array[0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
  find_context: PItemIDList;
  ptrWindows: Pointer;

begin
  DialogCaption := Caption;
  ShowCheckBox := DoCheckBox;

  FillChar(BrowseInfo, SizeOf(BrowseInfo), #0);
  FillChar(DisplayName, SizeOf(DisplayName), #0);

  lg_StartFolder := InitFolder;

  with BrowseInfo do begin
    hwndOwner := Application.Handle;
    pszDisplayName := @DisplayName[0];
    lpszTitle := PChar(Title);

    ulFlags := BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS or BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
    if not DoNewBtn then
      ulFlags := ulFlags or BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON; { Hide New Folder Button }

    if (InitFolder <> '') then
      lpfn := @BrowseForFolderCallBack;
    LPARAM := 0;
  end;

  ptrWindows := DisableTaskWindows(0);

  try
    lpItemID := SHBrowseForFolder(BrowseInfo);
  finally
    EnableTaskWindows(ptrWindows);
  end;

  if Assigned(lpItemID) then
  begin
    if SHGetPathFromIDList(lpItemID, DisplayName) then
      Result := DisplayName
    else
      Result := '';
    GlobalFreePtr(lpItemID);
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dir: String;
begin
  BrowseForFolder('Title', 'Caption', 'C:\', True, True);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why are you using `SHBrowseForFolder()`? It is not designed to be used this way. On Vista+, use `IFileDialog` instead (with its `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option). You can use `IFileDialogCustomize` to add your own child controls to the dialog. See the [`IFileDialogCustomize.AddCheckButton()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogcustomize-addcheckbutton) method and [`IFileDialogControlEvents.OnCheckButtonToggled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl/nf-shobjidl-ifiledialogcontrolevents-oncheckbuttontoggled) event.

Comment: See [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog) on MSDN for more details.  Delphi 6 is very very old, but it is still possible to use newer APIs in it, all you have to do is declare the relevant types in your own code, since they won't exist in Delphi 6's RTL for you. Though, you really should upgrade your Delphi to a modern version (which has supported this newer API for awhile now).

Comment: I'm using SHBrowseForFolder() because I want a simple browse for folder dialog that my customers have been using for more than 25 years. I'm familiar with IFileDialog, and use it elsewhere, but I don't want to use a File Dialog to browse for folders if I don't have to.

Comment: "*I don't want to use a File Dialog to browse for folders if I don't have to*" - why? It is the standard and preferred dialog to use on modern systems, for both files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by Embarcadero, it looks like I would need to go this route.

JAM Software ShellBrowser Delphi Components
[Creating Custom File Dialogs: ShellBrowser Delphi Components](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/creating-custom-file-dialogs-shellbrowser-delphi-components/)

Yes, I am aware these libraries are only supported on Delphi XE3 and later.

Comment: It is your choice, but it seems odd that you are willing to go to the trouble of upgrading your IDE and installing 3rd party components, just to replicate manually what the standard OS dialog (`IFileDialog` with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` flag) already offers you natively.

Answer (score 0):

Using Remy's suggestion, I produced the following: A File Dialog set to Pick Folders with a custom checkbox item.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnSelectFolder: TButton;
    BrowseForFolder: TFileOpenDialog;
    procedure BrowseForFolderOkClick(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure BrowseForFolderExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSelectFolderClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

const
  FB_CHECKBOX_ID = 4005;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.ShlObj;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TFBDialogEvents = class(TInterfacedObject, IFileDialogEvents, IFileDialogControlEvents)
  public
    { IFileDialogEvents }
    function OnFileOk(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnFolderChanging(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psiFolder: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnFolderChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnSelectionChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnShareViolation(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psi: IShellItem; out pResponse: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnTypeChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnOverwrite(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psi: IShellItem; out pResponse: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    { IFileDialogControlEvents }
    function OnItemSelected(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD; dwIDItem: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnButtonClicked(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnCheckButtonToggled(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD; bChecked: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnControlActivating(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

const
  dwVisualGroup1ID: DWORD = 1900;

var
  FB: IFileDialog = nil;
  FBEvents: IFileDialogEvents = nil;
  FBEventsCookie: DWORD = 0;

procedure TForm1.btnSelectFolderClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFolder: string;
begin
  BrowseForFolder.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
  if BrowseForFolder.Execute(Self.Handle) then begin
    // Do Something
    aFolder := BrowseForFolder.FileName;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BrowseForFolderExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  iCustomize: IFileDialogCustomize;
  iEvents: IFileDialogEvents;
  cookie: DWORD;

begin
  if Supports(BrowseForFolder.Dialog, IFileDialogCustomize, iCustomize) then begin

    if BrowseForFolder.Dialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialogCustomize, iCustomize) = S_OK then begin
      iCustomize.StartVisualGroup(0, 'Custom Caption');
      try
        iCustomize.AddCheckButton(FB_CHECKBOX_ID, 'Checkbox Caption', False);
        iCustomize.MakeProminent(FB_CHECKBOX_ID);
      finally
        iCustomize.EndVisualGroup;
      end;

      iEvents := TFBDialogEvents.Create;
      if Succeeded(BrowseForFolder.Dialog.Advise(iEvents, cookie)) then begin
        FB := BrowseForFolder.Dialog;
        FBEvents := iEvents;
        FBEventsCookie := cookie;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

// Grab the custom control's selection
procedure TForm1.BrowseForFolderOkClick(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  iCustomize: IFileDialogCustomize;
  IsChecked: LongBool;

begin
  if BrowseForFolder.Dialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialogCustomize, iCustomize) = S_OK then begin
    iCustomize.GetCheckButtonState(FB_CHECKBOX_ID, IsChecked);
  end;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnFileOk(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnFolderChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnFolderChanging(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psiFolder: IShellItem): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnOverwrite(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psi: IShellItem; out pResponse: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnSelectionChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnShareViolation(const pfd: IFileDialog; const psi: IShellItem; out pResponse: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnTypeChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnItemSelected(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD; dwIDItem: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnButtonClicked(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  if dwIDCtl = dwVisualGroup1ID then begin
    // ...
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else begin
    Result := E_NOTIMPL;
  end;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnCheckButtonToggled(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD; bChecked: BOOL)
   : HResult;
var
  IsChecked: LongBool;

begin
  pfdc.GetCheckButtonState(FB_CHECKBOX_ID, IsChecked);

  if IsChecked then
    // Do Somethihng
  else
    // Don't Do Anything

       Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TFBDialogEvents.OnControlActivating(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize; dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

end.
```

Which produces this:

[File Dialog (Select Folder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OckOu.jpg)

However, all I want is this:

[Browse For Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOe3j.jpg)